# Querying large table in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

I have very slow query which causes timeout error. I need all this data and sometimes even grouped by month.

Requirements are that I have to display data old 4 years. Results are displayed in a form of grid which has pagination so it must count all this results also which is performance intensive.

I was thinking about running crons which will calculate new rows so we don't have to use aggregated functions on flow, but what should I do with old data(100 millions of rows)?

Problematic Query - sometimes I need to group by and count results

```
SELECT
(SUM(onsite) / NULLIF(SUM(sessions),0)) as sumonsite,
SUM(onsite) as sum_onsite,
SUM(bounce_count) as bounce_count,
SUM(bounce_desktop) as bounce_pc,
SUM(bounce_mobile) as bounce_mobile,
SUM(bounce_tablet) as bounce_tablet,
(SUM(bounce_desktop) / NULLIF(SUM(uniques_desktop),0)) * 100 as bounce_pc,
(SUM(bounce_mobile) / NULLIF(SUM(uniques_mobile_phone),0)) * 100 as bounce_mobile,
(SUM(bounce_tablet) / NULLIF(SUM(uniques_tablet),0)) * 100 as bounce_tablet,
SUM(sessions) as sessions,
SUM(quality_3) as quality_3,
SUM(quality_2) as quality_2,
SUM(quality_1) as quality_1,
(SUM(amount)::float / NULLIF(SUM(uniques),0)) * 1000 as avg_cpc,
(SUM(bounce_count)::float / NULLIF(SUM(sessions),0)) * 100 as sumbounce,
(AVG(quality_3) / NULLIF(AVG(uniques),0)) * 100 as hq_quality,
(AVG(quality_2) / NULLIF(AVG(uniques),0)) * 100 as mq_quality,
(AVG(quality_1) / NULLIF(AVG(uniques),0)) * 100 as lq_quality,
SUM(cast(money_bonus as numeric(15,2))) as activity,
SUM(money_volume) as volume,
SUM(amount) as sumamount,
(SUM(clicks)::float / NULLIF(SUM(sessions),0)) as pages_per_visit,
SUM(add_par_1) as video_views,
SUM(add_par_3) as video_views_clicks,
((SUM(add_par_1)::decimal / NULLIF(SUM(sessions)::decimal,0))*100)::decimal(15,2) as sum_video_views,
100 * SUM(uniques_mobile_phone) ::FLOAT / SUM (uniques)::FLOAT AS uniques_mobile_phone,
100 * SUM(uniques_tablet)::FLOAT / SUM (uniques)::FLOAT AS uniques_tablet
FROM "aff_ref" "t" LEFT JOIN affiliate_domains ad ON ad.domain = t.referer AND ad.affiliate_id=t.affiliate_id WHERE ((DATE(day) >= '2013-12-14') AND (DATE(day) <= '2018-01-20'))
```

Table which is query

Size - 50 GB
  Number of rows - 94 917 680
  Every day ~500K new rows are added

```
    CREATE TABLE aff_ref
(
    site_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day DATE NOT NULL,
    affiliate_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    referer VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    uniques INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    uniques_hq INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    clicks INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    uniques_bounce_count BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    avg_clicks_all DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    bounce_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    bounce DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    onsite BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    avg_onsite DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    sessions INTEGER DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    quality_1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    quality_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    quality_3 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    hq_1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    hq_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    hq_3 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    add_par_1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    add_par_2 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    add_par_3 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    add_par_4 INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    add_par_5 BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    avg_videoviews DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    avg_searches DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_prime DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_prime_low DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_prime_bounce DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_bonus DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    amount DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    amount_basic DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    onsite_coef DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    pageviews_coef DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    videoviews_coef DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    searches_coef DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_volume DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    cpc DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    recur_direct INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    recur_search INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    totally_fresh INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    ntv_ctr REAL DEFAULT (0)::real NOT NULL,
    top_ctr DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    videofooter_ctr DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_alt DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    amount_alt DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    money_prime_old DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    amount_old DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    amount_por DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    por_id BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    amount_test INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    js_time BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    js_time_mouse BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    js_exists_count BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    js_not_exists_count BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    vp_un BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    vp_un_tr BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    nb_normal_hq BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    nb_normal_mq BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    nb_normal_lq BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    nb_embed_hq BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    nb_embed_mq BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    nb_embed_lq BIGINT DEFAULT (0)::bigint NOT NULL,
    custom_cpc DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    amount_old_cpc DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision NOT NULL,
    uniques_desktop INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    uniques_mobile_phone INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    uniques_tablet INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    clicks_desktop INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    clicks_mobile_phone INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    clicks_tablet INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    bounce_desktop DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision,
    bounce_tablet DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision,
    bounce_mobile DOUBLE PRECISION DEFAULT (0)::double precision,
    country VARCHAR(2)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ref_sites_day_aff_stype_idx ON aff_ref (day, site_id, affiliate_id, referer, country);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ref_sites_day_aff_stype_idx ON aff_ref (day, site_id, affiliate_id, referer);
```

Table which is joined 
size - 11 mb
count of rows - 107 278

```
    CREATE TABLE domains
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    affiliate_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    domain TEXT NOT NULL,
    checked_date TIMESTAMP,
    status SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    addedon_date TIMESTAMP(6),
    suspended_date TIMESTAMP(6),
    checked_via SMALLINT DEFAULT (1)::smallint NOT NULL,
    is_redirect SMALLINT DEFAULT (0)::smallint,
    compliance SMALLINT DEFAULT (-1) NOT NULL,
    note VARCHAR(512),
    CONSTRAINT domains_affiliate_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (affiliate_id) REFERENCES affiliates (affiliate_id)
);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX domains_affiliate_id_domain_key ON affiliate_domains (affiliate_id, domain);

Execution Plan:

    Aggregate  (cost=18169962.62..18169962.76 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=379233.584..379233.584 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on stats_aff_ref_sites t  (cost=0.00..8203606.20 rows=94917680 width=123) (actual time=0.005..159746.597 rows=94917677 loops=1)
        Filter: ((day >= '2013-12-14'::date) AND (day <= '2018-01-20'::date))
Planning time: 0.360 ms
Execution time: 379233.797 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: :) Great example of super human. Do you saw whoever who will read all the data returned from query? How much data size (bytes)?

Comment: Note that the cast `DATE(day)` is useless as `day` already is a `date`

Comment: Where's the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: The query doesn't use the `site_id` field which appears in the indexes. This means the server can't use the index to find a direct match, it has to can all entries for a day. Perhaps it chose not to use the index. Where's the execution plan?

Comment: The scenario you describe is a typical data mart - a small one. You need a different schema, appropriate for reporting. That's what star schemas are for. You *have* to know the type of reports that will be generated in order to design proper fact and dimension tables. Sales reporting is different from inventory or finance for example. All use dates, so a Calendar table with dates, weeks,months, years etc is required

Comment: Instead of the raw data, you should store rows in a fact table at the lowest level the *reports* need. For example, if you want aggregates by date, there's no need to go down to individual line items. Decide what the lowest level is in advance, eg (Product, Customer, Date,Salesman). Calculate aggregates for the measures on this level (Amount totals, counts, max, min values etc) and store them in the fact table. This reduces the volumen dramatically, eliminates nulls and makes querying a lot easier and faster. You could(should) index each column individually for example

Comment: You could consider using a multidimensional (cube) database on top of Postgres to preaggregate the data along the dimensions and hierarchies you define. Otherwise you'll have to calculate aggregations along the hierarchies. WITH ROLLUP or CUBE can create all the aggregations you want along they dimensions you define in GROUP By. Materialized views with indexes could help here too. BUT they require refreshing which will be just as expensive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actually PG can use index even if not all columns are matched. AFAIK - that is true for Oracle.

Comment: You could have a separate table of preaggregated data across all dimensions and a materialized view for the latest data (eg current week, month), copying its contents to the historical table every week

Comment: @Liminis - can you provide explain for that query? To me `DATE(DAY)` looks a bit problematic, since that is function call, and that can be problematic for index. Since `DAY` itself is `DATE` then you can skip `DATE` in your query.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski use yes, but how *effective* will it be and how expensive? The query processor could decide to ignore it. *Very* roughly, index fields are combined to create the index value and the value is stored in a B+-tree structure. If the index contained only the appropriate entries, the query processor could find the matching records simply by looking up the index value. Now it has to scan *all* of a day's values to find those that match the keys

Comment: @MichałZaborowski without the execution plan we can only guess anyway

Comment: @MichałZaborowski Postgres will ignore that function call if it is casting date(date_value). At least on 9.6 is see no change in query plan when I have added it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have filling that you are writing from general point of view, not specific to postgresql. Point is that this database can use this particular index. Since date is at first then rest is less relevant.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński yes - the same for me, but I don't have older PG, and not sure which version is used by OP.

Comment: @MichałZaborowski you misunderstood what I wrote. Instead of a lookup the database has to make a range search. And unless `date` has the best selectivity, performance may suffer. Which why I *really* want to see the execution plan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree that execution plan is key here. However your description of _potential_ plan is something else then PG usually do. For instance - index fields are not combined, and then putted to B+tree, they are putted one by one. [Here is doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) for that. Basically it scan index, collects `rowIds` and then queries for them from the table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have updated execution plan. I need count of all these results also for pagination.

Answer (score -1):

I see here 2 simple solutions:

- Never call the data you cannot use. Application have pages? Great - you can reduce your server load just by calling data for one page (ensure that where condition used indexed fiedls)
- Are you need aggregated data? Great - just create table with aggregation results split by some property value (think like day/week/month). The last (current month data) will be called from main table on the fly.

Comment: And the query that will calculate the aggregations will take just as long, resulting in the same timeout. And the OP *is* using paging, but requires a total count. Indexes? If you scroll down the definition of the first table you'll find them.

Comment: I think you mistaken here. There is no sense to call aggregation on historic data every time. You can call aggregation once per day. It could be started with cron or something more sophisticated. Also the date in where condition is great to reduce data amount for aggregation.

Comment: More sophisticated as in a proper star schema? Or a cube, or a different database that provides columnstores? What about full loads? No matter how well your incremental batch runs, you *will* have to run full loads from time to time. Hand-coding preaggregation isn't easy either. What do you do when you need to add *one* more level?

Comment: Lets focus on Postgre for now :). I not sure why you think I need to run full loads time to time? And one more question what is proper star schema? If you have better idea why to not post answer here?

Comment: Google for it, and "data warehouse".

Comment: Just googled. And know what? Now you should show "proper star schema" :) As for me it is not applicable here. Sorry